# SourceTree considers pulled files as uncommitted changes

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

In some unknown cases when I pull using SourceTree, it consider all pulled files as uncommitted changes and won't allow to pull/push any more unless re-commit or discard those changes.

If I discard uncommitted files, it will discard all the changes have been applied by my team-mate.

What's wrong with that? Is there a known bug or whatever?

Comment: what is the question again?

Comment: @nafas Are you familiar with Git and SourceTree? Isn't that clear?

Comment: u've edited the question since I asked, so now its clear :D

Comment: Was your last pull free of errors? Do you have checked the option "Commit merged changes inmediately"??

Comment: @mayo No I haven't checked that

Comment: Probably that is the reason: see:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/297456/what-exactly-commit-merged-changes-immediately-does
Tell me if it works to add an aswer ! ;)

Comment: @mayo Yes, that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too sure if this is the issue but it sounds similar.
When you pull, SourceTree pops up with a box. In this box there is a select box that reads.

> Commit merged changes immediately

If this isn't checked the pull will can come in as an uncommitted change. It sounds like this is happening. By removing these files you are creating a delete commit.