# In Sourcetree/Git other peoples committed changes appear in my 'uncommitted changes'

Tags: git, github, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I use Sourcetree to work on our Git branch. Sometimes in Sourcetree, I see other peoples committed changes to files appearing in my 'uncommitted changes' section. Then I need to discard/remove all of these changes from other people before I can do a git pull. Why would this be happening?

Comment: How did you view other people's commits, double click on a certain commit? If you have not commit changes before checkout HEAD, no matter where HEAD is, there always show the uncommitted changes.

Comment: On the Log/History tab, at the top of the table/grid view there is 'Uncommitted changes' that has my uncommitted changes. It is there that I see other peoples changes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your answer is related to [SourceTree considers pulled files as uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410181/sourcetree-considers-pulled-files-as-uncommitted-changes/33520372#33520372)
in which case when you pull, SourceTree pops up with a box. In this box there is a select box that reads.

> Commit merged changes immediately

I'm guessing that this isn't ticked so when you pull their changed appear as uncommitted.